# Function wont delete cookie (even though it works elsewhere)

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm having a bit of an issue deleting cookies in my JavaScript web-app. I've used this code in a separate function and it works just fine, but for some reason right now it doesn't actually change the expire time of the cookie for some strange reason, maybe I'm missing something obvious, but here's my code:

```
function deletetodo(obj) {

    var checkboxID;

    // get just the ID number of the checkbox.
    checkboxID = obj.id.replace(/todo-status-/g, '');

    // to make sure it's getting the right cookie ID (which it is)
    alert(checkboxID);

    // delete that cookie with the same ID number.
    document.cookie = "todo-" + checkboxID + '=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT;';

}
```

It's strange because in another function I have, this same code deletes a cookie, which then gets replaced with a small change at the end of the function.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: hi,did you check maybe path for the cookie? if you dont set path property it change cookie only for that page. So if you created cookie in other page,it will not be changed.

Comment: Yea, it's a single page app, I could add `path = /` just to have it in there, maybe that'd work. I'll try it out.

Comment: try to watch results after triggering that function in development tool like firebug or development tool in chrome to see what is going on.

Comment: adding `path=/` did the trick! Thanks man!

Comment: no problem, keep going :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was with the path not being set. Since it's a single page app, I just added `path=/;` after the expiry date.